# Fazer um retangulo/cone apenas com css

Tags: css

Teria como fazer tipo um retangulo/cone somente usando css? Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso usar como background de uma div ou botão, mas tem q ser nesse formato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.trapezio { 
  border-top: 50px solid blue; 
  border-left: 25px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 25px solid transparent; 
  height: 0; 
  width: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezio"></div>
```

[Eis uma excelente referência sobre como desenhar formas utilizando apenas o CSS](http://helabs.com/blog/2014/11/14/o-poder-do-css-3-desenhando-formas/)

Comment: Vlwwww!! Show de bola!

Comment: Downvoter poderia explicar o motivo de tanto ódio?